# Custom Language Resource file not getting deployed to server

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-4, embedded-resource, resx

We have an MVC 4 application that has 4 resource files. The default one (Resource.resx), one for Chinese and German (Resource.zn-CH.resx and Resource.de-DE.resx) and then one for a custom language (Resource.en-PI.resx (English-Pirate)) for testing purposes.

Every setting for all of the resource files is exactly the same:

- Build Action: Embedded Resource
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always
- Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
- Custom Tool Namespace: Resources

Whenever the application is built locally, in the bin folder we get the folders de-DE, en-PI and zh-CN which all include a dll named (ProjectName).resources.dll.

The problem is whenever this application is deployed to our DEV server the folder for en-PI is ignored and not copied and we have to manually copy that folder over for the en-PI language to work.

We have a build definition that will build the necessary projects to a certain folder and do other things and then copy them over to our DEV server.  Everything works perfectly fine for the other 2 languages (de-DE and zh-CN) but the en-PI folder doesn't show up in the bin folder.  Is there some setting somewhere that is causing this resource file not to be deployed because it is a custom language?

The way all of these resource files were added followed this example http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Microsoft explains it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618.aspx) under the section Resource Naming Conventions.  Because the language is a custom language and has a custom code it doesn't have a name that the common language runtime expects which is why it doesn't get deployed correctly.